# Use ES6 with npm in CLI mode

Tags: node.js, npm, ecmascript-6, ckeditor

I am trying to get CKEditor in my project with a custom build.

However, my problem is more general, so feel free to answer even if you don't use CKEditor.

Following [the instructions](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/development/custom-builds.html) to generate a custom build, I am getting a syntax error when running `npm run build` in terminal:

```
my/build/path/bin/create-entry-file.js:12
const { bundler } = require('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-utils');
      ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:140:18)
    at node.js:1043:3
```

Npm fails with a bunch of text and the above error. I believe this error is generated due to modern ECMAScript syntax, which is not recognized in my local machine.

However, the build I am trying to generate is there, complete and ready. Also, some other documentation of theirs, indicate more import {...} from syntax. This means that they are able to generate the build without the need of external packages (otherwise they would be in the package.json dependencies).

So, my question is, how do I install the software needed that will allow my npm to recognize and execute modern ES syntax ?

I am running on Ubuntu 16, with the lastest npm version: 5.6.0.

Thanks in advance, let me know if I can provide more information

Comment: Which Node.js are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, the problem was indeed the node version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please check the version of Node on your computer?

Run in the terminal

`node -v`

You need to have at least 6.4 as your Node.js version according to [this list](http://node.green/) on your computer

Here you have a link where you get and update to the newest version of Node 8.9.4 for different platforms. In your case check Linux

https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Comment: v4.8.4 here, updating now and will check

Comment: Updated to v9.6.1 and problem solved, thanks ! Wish I knew this sooner ...

Comment: [Here](https://askubuntu.com/a/548776/715011) is a nice list of command line solutions to update nodejs based on your system.